# How to import jquery/php into android studio

Tags: php, android, jquery

I would like to port my existing html/php/jquery code into an android app.

I've search all over and my results have been iffy. Is this even possible?

Comment: you need to do this manually , i think there is not a tool to port php to android for you , if it was a HTML5 & javascript app you can use phonegap but for the php i dont think so

Comment: How about just jquery and html5? I can hardcode data from PHP into html5 but I still need jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Check for "AQuery", Android-Query (AQuery) is a light-weight library tryin to do the same jQuery does.

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/